# GatsbyJS totally skips the Deploy step

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, aws-amplify

I have an issue that started yesterday evening.

We have a Gatsby install that pulls blog posts from Wordpress and deploys to AWS Amplify. When we push, the Build step looks completely normal, but the Deploy step only gives us the following :

```
2020-09-15T16:08:10 [INFO]: Starting Deployment
2020-09-15T16:08:10 [INFO]: Updating Edge config
uildId 0000000096
2020-09-15T16:08:18 [INFO]: Got archive: 510212896 bytes
2020-09-15T16:08:18 [INFO]: Archive unzipped: 7425 files
2020-09-15T16:09:06 [INFO]: Deployment complete
```

Normally, there's a few hundred lines telling us of JS/HTML files that were either uploaded or skipped.

As far as we know, nothing big changed on our WP install, and what did change (a single new post) we were able to delete, and clear the cache, and it didn't fix anything.

Same on Gatsby, there's been work done on it, but nothing that looks like a breaking change, and we didn't update any modules recently.

Moreover, it does the same thing on a completely different repo, which we haven't touched in months !

Did anyone else experience this ?

If it helps, here are our dependencies :

```
"@svgr/webpack": "^5.1.0",
"gatsby": "2.15.36",
"gatsby-image": "^2.2.30",
"gatsby-plugin-alias-imports": "^1.0.5",
"gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^2.1.15",
"gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.3.27",
"gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^2.1.15",
"gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.38",
"gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect": "^1.1.1",
"gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.6",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.13",
"gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker": "^1.0.0",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "2.2.22",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.19",
"gatsby-plugin-split-css": "^1.0.2",
"gatsby-plugin-svgr": "^2.0.2",
"gatsby-remark-images": "^3.1.29",
"gatsby-source-apiserver": "^2.1.3",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.35",
"gatsby-source-wordpress": "^3.1.46",
"gatsby-source-youtube-v2": "^1.0.1",
"gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.32",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.2.14",
"graphql": "^14.5.8",
"i18n-react": "^0.7.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
"react-countup": "^4.2.3",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
"react-hubspot-form": "^1.3.7",
"react-lazyload": "^2.6.2",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.51",
"react-scroll": "^1.7.14",
"react-share": "^4.2.0",
"react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
"react-swipeable": "^5.5.1",
"react-text-loop": "^2.3.0"
```

Thanks !

Comment: Gatsby doesn't deploy. Please update your post to include details about the plugin or code that was responsible for your deploy step.

Comment: I don't know where that code would be... Normally we just use the ```yarn build``` or ```npm run build``` command in the console and it takes care of both building and deploying.

And you say it doesn't deploy, but the changes pushed, do show up on most installs (just not all of them)...